# How to write rules for user on android firebase storage and cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am using firebase authentication in my app but I am confused how to write rules?,so that each user see only his data in app and update his data.
Like I have some `Map<String,Object>`(hashmap) in document`sampleData` and in collection is `information`.I read the guide but confused how do I edit rules ?
I tried

```
  service firebase.storage 
   {match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

but didn't work.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/ this is the official link. Can you able to tell where you are confused?

Comment: You can edit this rules from Firebase Console. Just go to your Project Path, and set read & write flag true. Read this  
firebase.google.com/docs/database/security  Carefully.

Answer (score 0):

please try this :
if request.auth==null;

Comment: tried that,it says user has not permission to access